# R output tukey results only where factors or interactions are significant (conditional statements)

Tags: r, anova, p-value, tukey

I'm relatively new to the R language, and using it to analyse my data. I am using a package called 'agricolae' and its HSD.test component to output tukeyHSD results based on the anova proceeding it. I have simplified the code below, but essentially the tukey code is run inside a for loop running through a list of factors/interactions. It works fine, however, I only want the loop to run where the anova result for the corresponding factor is significant. (i.e. <= 0.05).

```
f1 <- as.formula(paste(m,'~ Treatment + Genotype + GENOTYPExTREATMENT', sep = ''))
anova.result <- aov(f1, data = licor.data2)

treatment.list <- c('Treatment','Genotype', 'GENOTYPExTREATMENT')
        
for(t in treatment.list){ 
   tukey.result <- HSD.test(anova.result, trt = t)$groups
}
```

using `rownames(summary(anova.result)[[1]])`
returns `[1] "Treatment         " "Genotype          " "GENOTYPExTREATMENT" "Residuals        "`
and `str(summary(anova.result)[[1]])` returns:

```
Classes ‘anova’ and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Df     : num  4 6 24 99
 $ Sum Sq : num  0.01215 0.0019 0.00255 0.00527
 $ Mean Sq: num  3.04e-03 3.16e-04 1.06e-04 5.33e-05
 $ F value: num  57.02 5.94 1.99 NA
 $ Pr(>F) : num  7.22e-25 2.50e-05 9.68e-03 NA
```

Just wondering if someone knows how to construct a `when` or `if/else` statement which will only   run the loop code where the $Pr(>F) value for the corresponding 't' loop factor or interaction is less than 0.05.

thanks in advance,

Luke

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `DescTools` you may also want to look at my `Plot2WayANOVA` function which has this built in...

```
library(dplyr)
library(DescTools)

mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
MyAOV <- aov(mpg ~ am * cyl, mtcars)

sigfactors <- 
  filter(summary(MyAOV)[[1]], `Pr(>F)` <= 1 - .95) %>% 
  rownames %>% 
  trimws

if (length(sigfactors) > 0) {
  posthocresults <- PostHocTest(MyAOV,
                                method = "hsd",
                                conf.level = .95,
                                which = sigfactors)
} else {
  posthocresults <- "No signfiicant effects"
}

posthocresults
```

Which yields

```r
  Posthoc multiple comparisons of means : Tukey HSD 
    95% family-wise confidence level

$am
        diff  lwr.ci   upr.ci    pval    
1-0 7.244939 5.00149 9.488388 4.8e-07 ***

$cyl
         diff     lwr.ci     upr.ci    pval    
6-4 -4.756706  -8.399753 -1.1136596  0.0088 ** 
8-4 -7.329581 -10.365453 -4.2937086 7.2e-06 ***
8-6 -2.572874  -6.060826  0.9150773  0.1788    

---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Comment: Thanks Chuck for the quick reply, I was just coming back to answer my own question as i've managed to figure it our using base code with little modification to my existing program, i'll post it up.
Thanks, Again

Answer (score 0):

I got there using an if statement, and changing the for loop code to `1:length` to output the numerical positional in the list rather than the text itself. This in turn meant i had to update the treatment in the HSD.test function, not to output a number in place of 't' but the text using `treatment.list[t]` hope it makes sense!

```
for(t in 1:length(treatment.list)){ 
   if(summary(anova.result)[[1]][['Pr(>F)']][[t]] <= 0.05){
   tukey.result <- HSD.test(anova.result, trt = treatment.list[t])$groups


 } # end of if statement
} # end of for loop
```